# What is wrong with my trigger? No results are inserted

Tags: sql-server

The trigger below select ID's from one table (employeeInOut), sums int's in a column in that table matching all ID's, and is supposed to insert these in another table (monthlyHours).  I can't figure out if this is a syntax problem (nothing shows up in intellisense), and all it says is trigger executed successfully - nothing is inserted.

Trigger ->

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER empTotalsHoursWorked
ON employeeInOut
FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO monthlyHours(employeeID, monthlyHours)
SELECT (SELECT employeeID FROM employeeInOut),
SUM(dailyHours) AS monthlyHours
FROM employeeInOut
WHERE employeeInOut.employeeID=(SELECT employeeID FROM monthlyHours)
END
GO
```

I have re-worked this trigger many times and this is the one with no errors, however nothing is inserted, and results seem to be nothing.  Any advice, answers please appreciated.

Comment: If the table `monthlyHours` is empty to begin with then the predicate `WHERE employeeInOut.employeeID=(SELECT employeeID FROM monthlyHours)` will mean no results are returned. With that being said as soon as the table contains more than 1 row then you will get an error saying that the subquery returned more than one record, which is not valid when using the `=` operator. What is this `monthlyHours` table actually for? I can't really work out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  Basically I am just trying to match employeeID's in both tables (monthlyHours, employeeInOut), sum up daily hours (employeeInOut(dailyHours)) and put them in monthlyHours(monthlyHours)

Comment: Does monthlyhours have a column for EmployeeID because you aren't inserting to it. You also never reference the memory-resident tables `inserted` or `deleted` so your trigger is not relevant at all to the records that are inserted, deleted or updated. Is there any reason you need a second table to log this, and can't just use a query to get your sum - `SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(monthlyHours) FROM employeeInOut GROUP BY EmployeeID;`

Comment: Yes it does.  I edited to include your suggestions, but still no inserts.  To tell you the truth its probably more aesthetic that I have it in a totals table, easily accessible to whoever rather than running a query. Also why can't I see the results in the result pane other than "executed successfully"??

Answer (score 0):

I would really advise against a trigger for a simple running total like this, your best option would be to create a view. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MonthlyHours
AS
    SELECT  EmployeeID, 
            monthlyHours = SUM(dailyHours)
    FROM    dbo.employeeInOut
    GROUP BY EmployeeID;
GO
```

Then you can access it in the same way as your table:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MonthlyHours;
```

If you are particularly worried about performance, then you can always [index the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MonthlyHours
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT  EmployeeID, 
            monthlyHours = SUM(dailyHours),
            RecordCount = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM    dbo.employeeInOut
    GROUP BY EmployeeID;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_MonthlyHours__EmployeeID ON dbo.MonthlyHours(EmployeeID);
```

Now whenever you add or remove records from `employeeInOut` SQL Server will automatically update the clustered index for the view, you just need to use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` query hint to ensure that you aren't running the query behind the view:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MonthlyHours WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

Finally, based on the fact the table is called monthly hours, I am guessing it should be by month, as such I assume you also have a date field in `employeeInOut`, in which case your view might be more like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MonthlyHours
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT  EmployeeID, 
            FirstDayOfMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [YourDateField]), 0),
            monthlyHours = SUM(dailyHours),
            RecordCount = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM    dbo.employeeInOut
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [YourDateField]), 0);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_MonthlyHours__EmployeeID_FirstDayOfMonth 
    ON dbo.MonthlyHours(EmployeeID, FirstDayOfMonth);
```

And you can use the view in the same way described above.

---

**ADDENDUM**

For what it is worth, for your trigger to work properly you need to consider all cases:

1. Inserting a record where that employee already exists in `MonthlyHours` (Update existing).
2. Inserting a record where that employee does not exist in `MonthlyHours` (insert new).
3. Updating a record (update existing)
4. Deleting a record (update existing, or delete)

To handle all of these cases you can use `MERGE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER empTotalsHoursWorked
ON employeeInOut
FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH ChangesToMake AS
    (   SELECT  EmployeeID, SUM(dailyHours) AS MonthlyHours
        FROM    (   SELECT  EmployeeID, dailyHours
                    FROM    Inserted
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT  EmployeeID, -dailyHours
                    FROM    deleted
                ) AS t
        GROUP BY EmployeeID
    )
    MERGE INTO monthlyHours AS m
    USING ChangesToMake AS c
        ON c.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET MonthlyHours = c.MonthlyHours
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
        INSERT (EmployeeID, MonthlyHours)
        VALUES (c.EmployeeID, c.MonthlyHours)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        DELETE;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with a couple of assumptions here one being that monthlyHours table contains employeeID and monthlyhours.

With that being said I think you are going to need multiple triggers depending on the action.  Below is an example based on insert into the employeeInOut table

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER empTotalsHoursWorked
ON employeeInOut
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

       DECLARE @employeeID INT
       DECLARE @monthlyHours INT 

       SELECT @employeeID = INSERTED.employeeID      
       FROM INSERTED

    SELECT @monthlyHours = SUM(dailyHours) 
    FROM employeeInOut
    WHERE employeeInOut.employeeID = @employeeID


    INSERT INTO monthlyHours(employeeID,monthlyHours)
    values (@employeeID, @monthlyHours)

END
GO
```

This will insert a new row of course.  You may want to modify this to update the row if the row already exists in the monthlyHours table for that employee.

Comment: With all that being said @GarethD has the right approach.

Comment: Don't use scalar variables in triggers like this: `SELECT @employeeID = INSERTED.employeeID FROM INSERTED` - If there are multiple records in `inserted` then you are only dealing with one of them, and worse, there is no actual error to tell you this, the trigger works fine, and you may not realise for a while that the trigger is not doing a full job. **Always** write your triggers based on the assumption that the `inserted` and `deleted` tables will contain multiple rows, even if you think that will never happen.